# Why does my fisheye correction for a ray casting engine cause concaved walls?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, raycasting

I'm building the beginnings of a ray casting engine using HTML Canvas and I quickly ran into the fisheye effect problem. There's plenty of sites that tell you to just multiply the length of the ray by the cosine of its angle from the player to correct it.

```
distance * Math.cos(angle)
```

However, the fix only works on the y-axis of my map. On the x-axis it causes the walls to basically do the opposite of the fisheye effect. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Here's my code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

//Setup up map
var map = [];
for(var i = 0;i < 20;i++)
{
    map[i] = [];
}
map[0] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
map[1] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[2] = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2];
map[3] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[4] = [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[5] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[6] = [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2];
map[7] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[8] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[9] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[10] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[11] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[12] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[13] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[14] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[15] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[16] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[17] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[18] = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2];
map[19] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

var character = {
    x: c.width / 2,
    y: (c.height / 2) + 100,
    r: 25,
    angle: 0
};

//Define all rays
var rays = [];
for(var i = 0;i < 300;i++)
{
    rays[i] = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        travelling: false,
        hit: false,
        type: 0
    };
}

//GET INPUT
var turningLeft = false,
    turningRight = false,
    movingUp = false,
    movingDown = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);
window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, true);
function handleKeyDown(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case 87: movingUp = true;
            break;
        case 83: movingDown = true;
            break;
        case 65: turningLeft = true;
            break;
        case 68: turningRight = true;
            break;
    }
}
function handleKeyUp(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case 87: movingUp = false;
            break;
        case 83: movingDown = false;
            break;
        case 65: turningLeft = false;
            break;
        case 68: turningRight = false;
            break;
    }
}

function gameLoop()
{
    update();
    render();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update()
{
        
    //Allow movement
    if(movingUp)
    {
        if(!detectCharacterCollision(character.x + Math.cos(character.angle) * 2, character.y))
        {
            character.x += Math.cos(character.angle) * 2;
        }
        if(!detectCharacterCollision(character.x, character.y + Math.sin(character.angle) * 2))
        {
            character.y += Math.sin(character.angle) * 2;
        }
    }
    if(movingDown)
    {
        character.x -= Math.cos(character.angle);
        character.y -= Math.sin(character.angle);
    }
    if(turningLeft)
    {
        character.angle -= Math.PI / 180;
    }
    if(turningRight)
    {
        character.angle += Math.PI / 180;
    }
        
    //Cast ray
    for(var i = 0;i < rays.length;i++)
    {
        rays[i] = {
            x: character.x,
            y: character.y,
            travelling: true,
            hit: false,
            type: 0
        };
        
        //Until the ray hits a wall
        while(rays[i].travelling)
        {
            //Detect if ray has hit a wall
            var collision = detectRayCollision(rays[i].x, rays[i].y);
            //Collision has the type of wall which was collided with (0 for no wall)
            if(collision == 1)
            {
                rays[i].travelling = false;
                rays[i].hit = true;
                rays[i].type = 1;
            }
            else if(collision == 2)
            {
                rays[i].travelling = false;
                rays[i].hit = true;
                rays[i].type = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                //If nothing was hit, move ray is appropriate direction from player
                var angle = (i * ((Math.PI / 2) / rays.length)) - (Math.PI / 4);
                
                rays[i].x += Math.cos(character.angle + angle);
                rays[i].y += Math.sin(character.angle + angle);
            }
        }
    }
}

function detectRayCollision(x, y)
{
    return map[Math.trunc(y / (c.height / 20))][Math.trunc(x / (c.width / 20))];
}

function detectCharacterCollision(x, y)
{
    if(map[Math.trunc(y / (c.height / 20))][Math.trunc(x / (c.width / 20))] == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function getTime()
{
    var date = new Date();
    return date.getTime();
}

function render()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    
    //Skybox
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height / 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(135,206,250)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    //Floor
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, c.height / 2, c.width, c.height / 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    for(var i = 0;i < rays.length;i++)
    {
        var dx = rays[i].x - character.x;
        var dy = rays[i].y - character.y;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        var distance = Math.sqrt((dy * dy) + (dx * dx));
        var z = distance * Math.cos(angle);
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        
        //Set color (or texture) for wall
        if(rays[i].type == 1)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
        }
        else if(rays[i].type == 2)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
        }
        
        ctx.fillRect(i * (c.width / rays.length), (c.height / 2) - ((c.height / (z / 100)) / 2), c.width / rays.length + 1, c.height / (z / 100));
        
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

Answer (score 4):

I've answered my own question. I wasn't accounting for the direction the player is currently facing. So in my code the line for the fisheye correction should be:

```
var z = distance * Math.cos(angle - character.angle);
```